# How do i assign the Textbox value to Oracle SQL Query C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Assign entered texbox value to Sql query |C#|Oracle

**How do i assign the Textbox value to my SQL Query C#**

[image: C# Application UI]([UI]

In the Above Image i typed Tablename = PERSONDETAILS this entered value in textBox1.Text should be passed to my SQL Query as a Paramter.So Hard coding the table name in the SQl query will be reduced

Actual code where i want it to be Included

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',table_name,user) AS my_ddl from all_tables where owner ='HR' AND table_name ='PERSONDETAILS'"
```

**code :**

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = conString;
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("tableName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = texttablename.Text.ToString();
//cmd.CommandText = "select * from all_all_tables WHERE table_name=:tableName";
cmd.CommandText ="select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',table_name,user) AS my_ddl from all_tables where owner = :userid AND table_name = :tableName";
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox6.Text = reader.GetString(0);
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass value of a textbox as a parameter to your command through `Parameters` property of `OracleCommand`.

So all you need to include in your code is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from all_all_tables WHERE table_name=:tableName";
cmd.Parameters.Add("tableName", OracleType.VarChar, 20).Value =  textBox1.Text;
```

Update regarding comments:

```
cmd.CommandText ="select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',table_name,user) AS my_ddl from all_tables where owner = :userid AND table_name = :tableName";
// here you might want to use appropiate datatype
cmd.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("tableName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20).Value = texttablename.Text;
```

Comment: how do i pass value for this  -  cmd.CommandText ="select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',table_name,user) AS my_ddl from all_tables where owner =':userid' and table_name =':tableName'";

Comment: Michal can you help me out

Comment: @raj I don't understand... If you need to pass additional parameter, just follow the same logic and use: `cmd.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleType.VarChar, 20).Value =  "userId";` Just note that you need to choose appropiate datatype for this parameter (since it is ID I think integer would be good choice).

Comment: Michal : i have updated my post kindly look at it. it is working but for my actual query it is not working please guide me

Comment: @raj You got order of operations wrong, see my update.

Comment: order of operations means

Comment: @raj First you need to assign command text, then pass parameters.

Comment: Update regarding comments: this code is not working Michal

Comment: @raj Test your query if it is working. Code is correct and I can't help you anymore with it.

Comment: thanks Michal its working .... the value i entered in textbox is lower case i need to pass it as uppercase in paramter to assign it to my sql query